# What is the ObservableSet equivalent for setAll() method from ObservableList

Tags: java, collections, javafx, java-8

What method should I use in the setter of a JavaFX `ObservableSet` collection to clear the set and initialise it to the given collection? `ObservableList` has the method `setAll(Collection)` that is used to initialise the list by first clearing it.

The closest I have seen is `addAll(Collection)` which does not clear the set beforehand. When setting the collection in my project I want it to have the normal behaviour of setting the `ObservableSet` to a new set, but according to the javadoc:

> Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this set if they're not already present (optional operation). If the specified collection is also a set, the `addAll` operation effectively modifies this set so that its value is the union of the two sets.

I cannot just set the value using `=` because the passed parameter in the setter is a set and the `ObservableSet` is an internal wrapper that the outside knows nothing about. I also would like to avoid doing `clear` then `addAll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the Javadoc of [`ObservableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableSet.html), there is no such method.

In fact, the method [`ObservableList::setAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#setAll-java.util.Collection-) is just a convenient "shortcut":

> Clears the ObservableList and add all elements from the collection.

The common implementation [`ModifiableObservableListBase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ModifiableObservableListBase.html) in JavaFX does a `clear` then an `addAll`:

```
@Override
public boolean setAll(Collection<? extends E> col) {
    beginChange();
    try {
        clear();
        addAll(col);
    } finally {
        endChange();
    }
    return true;
}
```

The main advantage of having a `setAll` shortcut is that only one "big" [change event (`ListChangeListener.Change`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) is sent to the listeners. Better performance.

In fact, you might want to extend `com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableSetWrapper` with your own `setAll` but there will be no performance benefit since the event [`SetChangeListener.Change`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/SetChangeListener.Change.html) is an *elementary change*: `m` removed events, and `n` added events will be sent.

So you have no other choice than:

```
set.clear();
set.addAll(otherSet);
```

or copy in a new set and assign:

```
set = FXCollections.observableSet(otherSet);
```

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure there is nothing that an ObservableSet can be cast to to expose such a method. `set = FXCollections.observableSet(otherSet);` looks best because of readability and firing just one event